# Advice on my relational database query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Hi I have just started using relational databases at college and I am having trouble with queries when using multiple tables.  I normalized some data to the best of my knowledge as you can see below, however I am unsure how to write a query which will show me all of the products a particular customer has bought.  When I have tried it just shows me all products along with that 1 customer even if they have not bought anything.  Many thanks in advance!

[image: Relationship between my tables]

p.s I have looked for online documentation and vids on how to create multiple table queries but all I have found involve using one table.  If anyone can point me in the direction of a good source to learn this I would appreciate it! Thanks again.

Comment: Simply JOIN tables. Start with one join, verify results, add another join etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a simple inner join with the related table

```
select d.product_id, d.product_name
from invoce as a
inner join order as b on a.order_no = b.order_no
inner join customer as c on a.cust_no = c.cust_no
inner join product as d on b.product_id = d.product_id
```

Comment: thanks!, I had a couple of syntax errors with the code you provided however this was due to a minor spelling mistake invoce, and me using order as a table name (which is a reserved word) so I used back ticks to remedy that. I have now found plenty of material on JOINs which I wasn't aware of thanks again!